# Association rules during execution in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

I learned that expressions are left associative while abstraction are right associative, however, while solving some examples i faced this problem.
Succ 3 Succ 2
when i applied left associativety i got (Succ 3) Succ) 2
which was extremely long to solve.
However, i saw this guy on the internet, he said that we should parse it as Succ (3 Succ 2) which is Succ ( Succ Succ Succ 2) and the result is 6.
AND THE ANSWER IS RIGHT!
So now i am confused, during execution, should use the left or the right rule??

Comment: Application is left-associative (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Functions_that_operate_on_functions). `Succ ( Succ Succ Succ 2)` expansion can't possibly be correct since it doesn't follow any associativity rule, be it left or right. I also don't understand why `((Succ 3) Succ) 2` is extremely long to solve. 6 is indeed the correct answer.

Comment: so maybe it's not "extremely" long , but it's essential that i know the definition to solve it, unfortunately our test doesn't include a cheat sheet , so i don't think it's meant to be solved the conventional way.
Do you know of any fast way i can solve this without using the definitions ? 
https://lambdacalc.io/ this solver solved it in 49 steps which is unreasonably long for an MCQ question , that's why i said it was long

Comment: This can be solved in 2 steps, by definition of `Succ` and definition of what you get after simplifying `Succ 3`.